# Is it possible to send IOS push notification through pubnub on multiple applications?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, pubnub

I have two IOS applications and I want to send new message push notification on both applications through pubnub ? Is it possible ? As apple has different APNS certificate for different application and pubnub can use only one certificate at a time, is there any hack possible through which I can send push notification on multiple application ?

Comment: We understand the need for supporting multiple certs and we have a plan for it. I will reply with a detailed answer shortly.

Answer (score 2):

This is becoming a more common use case especially with the popularity of [car/taxi dispatch applications where you have a *driver* app that communicates with a separate *rider* app](http://www.pubnub.com/solutions/connected-car/). There are other use cases but this is the most common one.

Currently, the [PubNub Account Dashboard](https://admin.pubnub.com) only supports one push cert per key set which means you have a couple of workarounds until we do support multiple push certs per key set.

## Two Apps

1. Use 1 set of keys as the primary keys where you do all pub/sub operations, presences, etc.
2. You would also include the [mobile push payload](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/ios-objective-c/mobile-gateway-sdk-v4) (apns/gcm) in every publish you send.
3. One application will register for push notifications using this set of keys.
4. You will also publish the push payload *only* on the second set of keys that the other app will register for push notifications on.
5. That other app will also pub/sub, etc. on the first set of keys.
6. And each set of keys will have a separate push cert as you already understand.

## One App

The alternative is to just have one app (so one push cert with one set of PubNub keys) and you provide a means for the end user to register as a user of one module or the other (modules == apps now). Then just only show the functionality/UI that applies to that type of user. I understand this provides for a larger app footprint and more restrictive release cycles with both modules (apps) in a single app.

Neither of the above solutions are optimal but it is what many customers are implementing for now. We do have the **multi-push cert** feature on the roadmap but it requires some other features to be in place before we roll this out. Please follow @pubnub Twitter account and the [PubNub blog](http://www.pubnub.com/blog/) for announcements of this feature and other great improvements that are coming soon.

### Questions (from the comments)

1. Lets say I have two apps, one is driver and another is rider, do I have to create two apps on pubnub and get two set of keys?
2. As far as I understood from your explanation, after creating two apps on pubnub, we will have to use one keys for chat and another for push notification, am I correct?
3. In case of using another keys only for push notification, how will it identify to which rider app or driver app it has to send push notification?

### Answers

*I am answering all three questions in one shot here. I hope this makes it clear.*

Apps in the PubNub Account Dashboard are basically just organizational folders so they don't really have to have a direct relationship to an actual application, so it really doesn't matter if you create 1 or 2 *Apps* in this scenario. But I would create 1 *App* and two sets of keys: *Primary* keys and *Secondary* keys. Both of your iOS apps (Driver and Rider) will use the Primary keys for all pub/sub of messages.

But for push notifications, Driver app will register for push notifications only on the Primary key's push cert and the Rider app will only register for push notifications on the Secondary key's push cert. Whenever you publish a message to the Primary key, you include the push notification payload for APNS (`pn_apns : { aps : { alert :...`) *and* you also publish *just* the push notification payload on the Secondary key.

Comment: Thanks craig for detailed answer but I have few questions here : 1. Lets say I have two apps, one is driver and another is rider, do I have to create two apps on pubnub and get two set of keys ? 2. As far as I understood from your explanation, after creating two apps on pubnub, we will have to use one keys for chat and another for push notification, am I correct ? 3. In case of using another keys only for push notification, how will it identify to which rider app or driver app it has to send push notification ?

Comment: I edited the answer to address your questions. I hope my explanation is clear.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, just to conclude my understanding : we will be having 1 app with 2 keys with different APN certificates and we will be using primary key for all communication and send notification payload to secondary key as well to deal with notification issue.